# How to pass parameters to custom validator function in angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

This is how i validate password, confirm password & email, confirm email. As you can see i have a function fieldMatcher which is called to check for email and password validation.

```
// Works

createForm() {
            this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                email: '',
                confirmEmail: '',
                password: '',
                confirmPassword: '',
            }, {validator: this.fieldMatcher});
        }
        fieldMatcher(c: AbstractControl): { invalid: boolean } {
            if (c.get('password').value !== c.get('confirm').value) {
                return {invalid: true};
            }
            if (c.get('email').value !== c.get('confirmEmail').value) {
                return {invalid: true};
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to pass the controls to the fieldMatcher function as a parameters so that i reduce the code like below but that do not work,

```
// Do not Work
createForm() {
        this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            confirmEmail: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: '',
        },{validator: this.fieldMatcher(value1, value2)});
        }
        fieldMatcher(c: AbstractControl, value1, value2): { invalid: boolean } {
            if (c.get(value1).value !== c.get(value2).value) {
                return {invalid: true};
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Thats because your `value1` and `value2` does not correspond to any at all. You need to send in the key instead of `value1` and `value2`. Take the reference from below example.

**Working Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/RlWslfyr1eiTq4MSc3iY?p=preview

```
import {Component, FormBuilder, Control, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [ng-form-model]="form">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" ng-control="name">
      <br>
        <div ng-control-group="matchingEmail">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" ng-control="email">
      <br>
      <label for="confirmEmail">Confirm Email:</label>
      <input id="confirmEmail" type="email" ng-control="confirmEmail">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div ng-control-group="matchingPassword">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" ng-control="password">
        <br>
        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" ng-control="confirmPassword">
      </div>
    </form>
    <p>Valid?: {{form.valid}}</p>
    <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre>
  `
})
export class App {
  form: ControlGroup
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: [''],
        matchingEmail: fb.group({
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        confirmEmail: ['', Validators.required]
      }, {validator: this.fieldMatcher('email','confirmEmail')}),
      matchingPassword: fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.required],
        confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
      }, {validator: this.fieldMatcher('password','confirmPassword')})
    });
  }

 fieldMatcher(value1: string, value2: string) {
  return (group: ControlGroup) => {
    if (group.controls[value1].value !==  group.controls[value2].value) {
      return group.controls[value2].setErrors({notEquivalent: true})
    }
  }
}

}
```

Comment: But where is the abstract control here?

Comment: i am using controlGroup to access the data. Revise mine to use the abstract control. Its the logic that you have done wrong.

Comment: can you share your whole component.ts?

Comment: what do you mean by required code? you want me to code it for you? can you please copy paste the code thats throwing error so that i can debug. As far as i can see the error is because you need to send in the field name instead of value1 and value 2 :/

Comment: will send that soon.

Comment: I wanted to send you the code, I see that the code is already here. You dont have to code for me.