# Angular library validator directive not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I was trying to build an angular library for custom validator directive which can validate confirm password but as i build that library and publish on local npm and imported in my project it is throwing **ERROR TypeError: tView is null** error. here is codes

**src\lib\confirm-password-validation.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appConfirmPasswordValidation]',
  providers:[{
    provide:NG_VALIDATORS,
    useClass:ConfirmPasswordValidationDirective,
    multi:true
  }]
})
export class ConfirmPasswordValidationDirective {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Form Directive')
   }
  validate(form:FormGroup|any): ValidationErrors | null {
    if(!form.controls.password || !form.controls.confirmPassword){
      return null;
    }
    if(form.controls.password.errors && form.controls.confirmPassword.errors){
      return null;
    }
    if(form.controls.password.value !== form.controls.confirmPassword.value){
      form.controls.confirmPassword.setErrors({matchPassword:true});
      return {matchPassword:true}
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**src\lib\confirm-password-validation.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmPasswordValidationComponent } from './confirm-password-validation.component';
import { ConfirmPasswordValidationDirective } from './confirm-password-validation.directive';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ConfirmPasswordValidationComponent,
    ConfirmPasswordValidationDirective
  ],
  imports: [],
  exports: [
    ConfirmPasswordValidationComponent,
    ConfirmPasswordValidationDirective
  ]
})
export class ConfirmPasswordValidationModule { }
```

**src\public-api.ts**

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of confirm-password-validation
 */

export * from './lib/confirm-password-validation.service';
export * from './lib/confirm-password-validation.component';
export * from './lib/confirm-password-validation.module';
export * from './lib/confirm-password-validation.directive';
```

**After publish i have installed in my project**

**src\app\app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ConfirmPasswordValidationModule } from 'confirm-password-validation';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ConfirmPasswordValidationModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**src\app\app.component.html**

```
<div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="card p-5">
    <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" appConfirmPasswordValidation>
      <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" formControlName="password">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" formControlName="confirmPassword">
        <p>
          <span *ngIf="confirmPassword?.hasError('matchPassword')">
                    Password Mismatch
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check mb-3">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ERROR**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're blending [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-reactive-forms) and [template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms) forms. you'll want to pass in your custom validator when you instantiate the form group in TS rather than use a template-based validator directive. this [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405151) does pretty much exactly what you need. in your library, you can just export a `fieldMatcher()` or `passwordValidator()` top-level function or encapsulated static method